# What is the criteria for encoding a mirrored version of a character in Unicode?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, character, bidi

What is the criteria for encoding a mirrored version of a character in Unicode? There seems to be a lot of inconsistencies in currently encoded characters. For eg:

1. '∼'(U+223C, Tilde operator) is mirrored with '∽'(U+223D, Reversed tilde). But similar looking (why there are two characters for tilde is yet another question by itself :|) '~'(U+007E, Tilde) is not mirrored with anything.
2. '≃'(U+2243, Asymptotically equal to) is mirrored with '⋍'(U+22CD, Reverse tilde equals). Whereas related '≄'(U+2244, Not asymptotically equal to) and '≈'(U+2248, Almost equal to) are mirrored but don't have dedicated characters.
3. '≾'(U+227E, Precedes or equivalent to) is wrongly mirrored with '≿'(U+227F, Succeeds or equivalent to), since it's upper half is only mirrored here and the lower half remains unmirrored.

Is there any source from where I can know *why* a character was encoded in UCS standard? Like many redundant characters have been encoded for legacy compatibility reasons. But there many other which I don't understand, like, if mirror of '≈'(U+2248, Almost equal to) is left to the rendering system while mirror of '≃'(U+2243, Asymptotically equal to) is explicitly encoded. I know Mirror of '<'(U+003C, Less-than sign) is also encoded. But it just so happens to be another different character '>'(U+003E, Greater-than sign), unlike the above case.

Comment: Just guessing, but is it determined by the semantics of those characters when switching between right-to-left and left-to-right writing systems, at least in some cases? In the case of ALMOST EQUAL TO, if `pi ≈ 3.14` in LTR, then `3.14 ≈ pi` is still valid in RTL; you can use `≈` in both cases. But for ASYMPTOTICALLY EQUAL TO, if `pi ≃ 3.14159` in LTR then I don't think it is equally valid to write `3.14159 ≃ pi` in RTL; you need to use the mirrored character `⋍` in place of `≃`  (i.e. `3.14159 ⋍ pi`). More generally, if the relationship is symmetric you don't need a mirrored character...

Comment: ...But I'm sure there's more to it than that. I just considered some of your examples, but Unicode has hundreds of mirrored characters and I doubt that they all relate to symmetric relationships, or directionality. Your question is interesting, but it is arguably too broad and off topic for SO.

Comment: Not sure about semantics. Although, those two characters doesn't seem to differ in semantics. If this is off topic for SO, you think of any other SE sites where this would be appropriate?

Comment: Well I think they fundamentally differ semantically, even though they are both relational operators. Consider two simpler choices: `=` (equals) and `<` (less than). If  `a = b` then switching directionality yields `b = a`, which is fine, so there is no need for Unicode to mirror `=`. In contrast, if `a < b` then switching directionality yields `b < a` which is wrong, so `<` needs a mirror of `>`, to correctly yield `b >  a` when changing directionality. Does that make any sense? I admit it's just speculation, but the same argument could be applied to a lot of the other mirrored characters.

Comment: You might consider asking on [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/). It has quite a few unusual questions on Unicode. But since Unicode has hundreds of mirrored characters, you might also want to provide a bit more context for your question. There's also https://www.reddit.com/r/Unicode/ where (unlike SE sites) you won't have to worry about framing your question so that it is on topic.